# `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` while trying to register a user in node rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, rest

I'm trying to create a register route in my NodeJS rest api, but whenever I try to send the data to the db, it's showing me some error like `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.
I know what's the meaning of the error but, don't know why this error is coming here.
Here's my register route code:

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const gender = req.body.gender;
  const country = req.body.country;
  const password = req.body.passwordHash;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: " + err);
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        phone,
        gender,
        country,
        passwordHash: hash,
      });
      try {
        const savedUser = await newUser.save()
        res.send(savedUser)
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err)
      }
      
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: in the callback in bcrypt.hash() add async before (err, hash) => ...

Comment: @fonzane Yes that's what I've said in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is inside the `(err, hash) =>` function. So you need `async (err, hash) =>`, not `async (req, res) =>`.